# How to extract highest voted model instances in acts_as_votable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say that I have a post model that is under the acts acts_as_votable plugin. How can I take the top 30 posts with the highest vote counts? It should be pretty simple; however, I cannot locate any documentation within the plugin that elaborates on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realize that this is an old question, nonetheless I ran into the same issue and felt like leaving here my solution. Thus, the way I accomplished that was by running the migration below, as the [documentation](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) describes.

```
class AddCachedVotesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_score, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :posts, :cached_votes_down, :integer, :default => 0
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_total
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_up
    add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_down
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_score
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_up
    remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_down
  end
end
```

Then in my model I added the class method below

```
class Post
  def self.highest_voted
    self.order("cached_votes_score DESC")
  end
end
```

Afterwards, `Post.highest_voted` will return the highest voted posts.

In order to return just 30 posts, you can do something like `Post.highest_voted.limit(30)`

Comment: Nice answer @Luis