# SQLite, Ruby on rails. How to get the top voted objects with acts_as_votable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I"m trying to display the best 3 Recipes from the last 7 days.
The best is dependant on the amount of votes it has using the acts_as_votable gem but i have not created a cache.
current user.rb, limits to the last 7 days

```
def featuredfeed
    Recipe.where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - 1.week)
  end
```

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable

  ....

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

end
```

the votes table is ordered

```
id, votable_id, votable_type, voter_id, voter_type, vote_flag, vote_scope, vote_weight, created_at, updated_at
```

The votable_id is the id of the recipe which needs to be counted for the number of times it has been upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to say, that caching votes is much cleaner solution, than the following one. It is just a matter of adding a new migration. But up to you..

Get the ids of recent recipes (this part you already have done):

```
recipes_ids = Recipe.where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - 1.week)
```

Filter the votes for this recipes:

```
Vote
  .where(votable_id: recipes_ids)
```

Group them by `votable_id`:

```
  .group(:votable_id)
```

And find those, which have more, at least 1 vote:

```
  .having('count(votable_id) > 1')
```

Now take the ids of 3 most upvoted recipes:

```
most_voted_recipes_ids = Vote
  .where(votable_id: recipes_ids)
  .group(:votable_id)
  .having('count(votable_id) > 1')
  .limit(3).votable_ids # or limit(3).pluck(:votable_id)
```

And, lastly, find those most popular recipes:

```
most_popular_recipes = Recipe.where(id: most_voted_recipes_ids)
```

Comment: Is it possible to sort each recipe for the most upvotes during the last 7 days?

Comment: @andrey-deineko As you said using cached_votes is better solution. Would you provide such examples?

Comment: @egyamado this is "a bit" old question and I am not sure what I meant back then, but [here's what googling gave me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719604/how-to-extract-highest-voted-model-instances-in-acts-as-votable) - hope it helps :)