# Rails: outputting data where record has more votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-votable

Right now I have this

```
def index
  @trips = Trip.all
end
```

And I'm outputting data like so:

```
- @trips.order('created_at desc').first(4).each do |trip|
  - trip.trip_images.first(1).each do |image|
    = trip.title_name.titleize
```

However, I have a votable table (from acts_as_votable gem) associated to trips. I was wondering if I can only output trips where trips have a certain amount of votes?

I can get the votes like this:

```
- @trips.order('created_at desc').first(4).each do |trip|
  = trip.get_likes.size #this is where I can get the likes
  - trip.trip_images.first(1).each do |image|
    = trip.title_name.titleize
```

**EDIT**

If I do this instead:

```
def index
  @votes = ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).count
  @trips = Trip.where(@votes)
end
```

`@votes` gives me something like this:

`{195=>1, 106=>1, 120=>1, 227=>1, 247=>1, 264=>1, 410=>1}`

How do I get it where trip will only get the ids?

**EDIT 2**

I think I figured it out...

```
def index
  @votes = ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).count
  @trips = Trip.where(id: @votes.keys)
end
```

I got some kind of output. Is there a better way?

Comment: you can do the other way around... like instead of getting trips that have certain number of likes from Trip model.. Try to get them from `votable` table

Comment: Adding to the comment by @Minato, you could try something like `ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).count` which would give you the number of votes for each voted trip id.

Comment: @awin I see what's going on... I edited my question if you can help me on how I would get the ids from a where statement?

Comment: @awin I think I was able to figure it out... but is there a better way than what the code from the second edit?

Comment: try `@votes = ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).select("votable_id as id").where("count(votable_id >= #{desiredLikes})").map(&:id)`

Comment: @hellomello I know its a long statement... :P but you gotta do what you gotta do.. then `@trips.find(@votes)`

Comment: @Minato I may be doing this wrong, but I get this error: `ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE LINE 1: ...OM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_type" = $1 AND (count(vota...` I replated the `#{desiredLikes}` with an integer, I assume? Not sure if thats the cause of the issue...

Comment: `@votes = ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).select("votable_id as id, count(votable_id) as likes ").where(" likes >= #{desiredLikes}").map(&:id)`

Comment: @hellomello I mistakenly put the `)` after `#{desiredLikes}` like `"count(votable_id >= #{desiredLikes})"` instead of `"count(votable_id) >= #{desiredLikes}"`

Comment: @Minato I tried them both, but still getting errors

Comment: @Minato I don't think the count within the .where statement can work like that?

Comment: @hellomello `@votes = ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).select("votable_id as id, count(votable_id) as likes ").map {|t| t.id if t.likes >= desiredLikes}`

Comment: @hellomello I just realized you are not allowed aggregate function in where its the first time I noticed such thing.. THANKS :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I answered [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122415/1772830).

This is how you could get the id(s) of trip with certain amount of votes (you can use `=`, `>`, `<=` and so on):

```
trip_ids = ActsAsVotable::Vote
  .where(votable_type: 'Trip')
  .group(:votable_id)
  .having('count(votable_id) > 1') #any number of votes
  .pluck(:votable_id)
  .uniq

Trip.where(id: trip_ids)
```

Comment: did you try `pluck(:votable_id).uniq`? It shoupd work with pluck

Comment: Edited the answer with `pluck` :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making this a method in your `Trip` model?

Something like,

```
def popular_trip_images
  Trip.select(:trip_images).where("likes > ?", 200)
end
```

Then use it something like,

```
...
trip.popular_trip_images.each do |image|
...
```

Edit:

> However, I have a votable table (from acts_as_votable gem) associated to trips. I was wondering if I can only output trips where trips have a certain amount of votes?

Sorry, missed this part. The gem has a `find_liked_items` method but don't see offhand how to set something like `liked > 400` etc.

Comment: Don't think the `likes` works because its not a column in the `Trip` table. I'm using `acts_as_votable` gem

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to work through the comments, but right now, I've gotten this code to work:

```
def index
  @votes = ActsAsVotable::Vote.where(votable_type: 'Trip').group(:votable_id).count
  @votes = @votes.select {|k,v| v > 1}
  @trips = Trip.where(id: @votes.keys)
end
```

If someone else can come up with a better solution! I'll mark as correct.